# How to prove $\sum n/3^n$ converges without ratio test?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The only tests my class has learned so far and is allowed to use are: Divergence, Integral, Comparison, Geometric/Harmonic/Telescopic. I have proved that the series converges, via a ratio test, but my teacher doesn't want me to use that. I don't think I can do an integral test; it defnitely isn't a geometric series because the numerator increases arithmetically. It isn't any sort of p-series, not telescopic. That leaves the comparison test -- except I don't know what to compare it to. I tried $b_n = 1/3^n$, and while this converges, it's smaller than $a_n$.

As a side note, are there any tricks for finding good comparisons, or do you just develop an intuition over time?

Comment: You *can* use the integral test, as you can integrate $f(x)=x3^{-x}$ (which is positive and decreasing for sufficiently large $x$) using integration by parts.

Comment: We could compare with $1/(1.1)^n$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I don't understand. If I try to do a direct comparison, I can't conclude that $1/(1.1)^n$ is greater or smaller because the numerator is smaller ($b_n$ is smaller overall) but the denominator is also smaller ($b_n$ is greater overall). So I could use a comparison of $lim ( a_n / b_n)$, but I got stuck with $lim (1.1/3)^n * n$.

Comment: We show that $\frac{n}{3^n}\lt \frac{1}{(1.1)^n}$ by showing $(3/1.1)^n\gt n$. Actually, we could use $1.5$, and show that $2^n\gt n$.

Comment: Oh, I never even thought of manipulating it like that! My book typically just looks at the denominator or numerator and makes a decision based on that (eg. "denominator has less terms but same degree? it's smaller, so the number overall must be bigger" etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine techniques.  For example $\sum b_n$ where $b_n=2^n/3^n$ converges as a geometric series.  On the other hand, $n/3^n < b_n$, so your sum converges by the comparison test.

Comment: Sorry, I can't seem to figure out how to prove that $2^n > n$.

Comment: You could try induction.

Comment: Working on it....

Comment: So I've never really done proof by induction for these, so here's what I got: start with the base case $2^n>n$ for $n=1$, and assume true for n=k. I need to get to $2^{k+1}>k+1$, so starting with $2^k>k$, I multiply by 2 --> $2^{k+1}>2k$, --> $2^{k+1} / 2 > k$, and if the inequality holds for this then it will hold when adding 1 to both sides. The left isn't exactly what I want, but $a/2 < a$ for any number a, implying that $2^{k+1}/2 < 2^{k+1}$. If it works for $2^{k+1}/2$, it will work for $2^{k+1}$ and so $2^{k+1} > k$. As for adding 1 to both sides, can I ignore this as insignificant?

Comment: You are on the right track.  Once you get to $2^{k+1}>2k$ just note that $2k \geq k+1$ since $k\geq 1$.  Thus $2^{k+1}>2k \geq k+1$ which gives the induction step

Comment: Oh, smart. I actually wrote down something similar but ended up dismissing it because it didn't hold for all k; but I realize you're right, I just needed it for $k >= 1$. Thanks for your patience with this, I feel like I learned a lot from it.

Comment: Thank you for actually putting in the work and showing your thoughts.  Too many people on this site just want other people to do their homework for them.